# Axios only fetches Azure API response ONCE

Tags: reactjs, azure, axios, azure-blob-storage, azure-api-management

I am trying to fetch my blobs with axios inside my React app using the Azure REST API (and parse it to JSON as it comes in as a XML response). Problem here is that it fetches correctly once, and when the page is refreshed it does not fetch anything else, showing undefined whenever I try to access any of the data, and returning empty array in console... what am I doing wrong?

```
const [images, setImgs] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const response = await axios.get(`https://${process.env.AZURE_SPACE}.blob.core.windows.net/${process.env.AZURE_CONTAINER}?restype=container&comp=list&${process.env.AZURE_TOKEN}`);
      const newJson = JSON.parse(convert.xml2json(response.data, {compact: true, spaces: 4}))
      setImgs(newJson);
    }
  fetchData();
  console.log(images)
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
await fetchData();
```

Otherwise, your console log is called before the answer coming back from azure

Comment: I can't do that as the call to `fetchData()` is inside `useEffect()`, which doesn't support using async directly.

Answer (score 0):

So, if you checking `console.log(images)` why this is still blank :

```
setImgs(newJson); // is also async 

fetchData(); 
console.log(images) //<-- So it won't reflected immediately right after fetchData()
```

But your DOM will get updated, you can confirm it.

---

You can run the below snippet and check HTML and `conosle.log` both :

```
setUsers([...users, "Vivan" , "Darshita"]); // is async 
console.log(users); // Due to setUsers's async behaviour it still console.log old values
```

```js
const { useState , useEffect } = React;

const App = () => {

  const [users,setUsers] = useState(['Vivek' , 'Darsh']);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setUsers([...users, "Vivan" , "Darshita"]);
      console.log(users);
    },2000);
  },[]);

  return (
    <div>
      { users.map(user => <p>{user}</p>) }
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('react-root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react-root"></div>
```

Comment: Well I moved to `console.log()` outside which now shows that it is indeed fetching and populating the array correctly on each mount of the component, however it still only let's me access this once (with a map) and comes out as undefined upon second refresh, even though the array is there

Comment: @PRR, There might be something else then, create a demo over stackblitz or codesandbox, whatever suits, so I can help you more.

Answer (score 0):

So it sounds like two separate questions.

How to solve the await issue:

```
const [images, setImgs] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
const wrapperFunc = async () => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const response = await axios.get(`https://${process.env.AZURE_SPACE}.blob.core.windows.net/${process.env.AZURE_CONTAINER}?restype=container&comp=list&${process.env.AZURE_TOKEN}`);
      const newJson = JSON.parse(convert.xml2json(response.data, {compact: true, spaces: 4}))
      setImgs(newJson);
    }
  await fetchData();
  console.log(images)
};
wrapperFunc();
}, []);
```

The code inside the wrapperFunc can now wait for fetchData to return before writing to the console.

The second issue where it is only getting called once. It could be fixed as a result of this new code. However, I ran into something similar with React Hot Loading where the gating state was already set, so it would rerun my new code. I had to just change the state manually and then the code ran.